# KVM: Multiple bridges over single NIC

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge

In my KVM host (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) I want to setup one private network for the guests with static IP and internet access. Host is on a remote machine. I've the following configuration in the `etc/network/interfaces`

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Local network interface
auto br1
iface br1 inet static
    address 10.0.0.1
    network 10.0.0.0
    netmask 255.255.255.224
    broadcast 10.0.0.31
    bridge_ports eth1
    bridge_fd 9
    bridge_hello 2
    bridge_maxage 12
    bridge_stp off

# The primary network interface and bridge
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address xx.xx.xx.xx
    gateway xx.xx.xx.xx
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network xx.xx.xx.xx
    broadcast xx.xx.xx.xx
    dns-nameservers xx.xx.xx.xx xx.xx.xx.xx
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_fd 9
    bridge_hello 2
    bridge_maxage 12
    bridge_stp off
```

Now, I install the guests with the command like:

```
virt-install \
--name ubuntu1 \
--ram 256 \
--disk path=/var/kvm/images/ubuntu1.img,size=5 \
--vcpus 1 \
--os-type linux \
--os-variant ubuntutrusty \
--network bridge=virbr0,model=virtio \
--network bridge=br1,model=virtio \
--graphics none \
--console pty,target_type=serial \
--location 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/installer-amd64/' \
--extra-args 'console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial'
```

I make the virbr0 as the primary interface and the installation completes successfully. After installation, I had set the `/etc/network/interfaces` in guest as:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# Local network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 10.0.0.2
    network 10.0.0.0
    netmask 255.255.255.224
    broadcast 10.0.0.31
```

With this, the guests gets the internet access from `virbr0` and with `br1` gets a static ip in the internal private network.

Now, my question is that, can I add a bridge something like:

```
# Local network interface with network connection
auto br2
iface br2 inet static
    address 10.0.0.33
    network 10.0.0.32
    netmask 255.255.255.224
    broadcast 10.0.0.63
    dns-nameservers xx.xx.xx.xx xx.xx.xx.xx
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_fd 9
    bridge_hello 2
    bridge_maxage 12
    bridge_stp off
```

So, that the guests can be in the private network with a static, as well as connected to the internet with only one interface.

But after I restart the host with this, two bridges on `eth0` and one bridge on `eth1`, the host is lost. Can't log into it with ssh. As the host is remote, I can't access it physically.

Please help. Thanks in advance.